# Show order weight upon checkout

Tags: checkout, invoice

I've been looking for a solution on how to get total ordered products weight displayed upon checkout on the frontend, in the notification email, sent to admin and in the invoice.

I would appreciate very much if you can give me some hints.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? Please edit your question, add what you tried and what doesn'T work as expected and then request reopening.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the total order weight in Shopping Cart page!

Following are few links that might help you:

http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-can-i-show-the-total-weight-in-the-cart-63-nbsp--30716.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549006/display-total-weight-of-cart-in-the-magento-header